# Dojo scope issue with "inner" require

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm sure "inner require" isn't the correct term, but it'll make sense here shortly.  I'm working on the Dijit tutorials from the toolkit's site, and I'm running into an issue that I think is more a Javascript understanding than a Dojo one.

My page init script:

```
require(['player', 'dojo/dom', 'ready'], function(Player, dom){
    var p = new Player({
        type : 'video',
        dimensions : [720, 480]
    });
    p.setSource('videos/myvideo.webm')

    p.placeAt(dom.byId('stage') )
})
```

And my constructor of the dijit "player.js"

```
constructor : function(opts){
    (function($){
        require(['sg/player/component/Video', 'sg/player/component/Audio'], function(Video, Audio){
            $._setMedia( (opts.type == 'video') ? new Video() : new Audio());
            console.log($._media) // outputs an object "a"
        })
    })(this);
    console.log(this._media) // also outputs the correct object, "a"
}

// the internal setter function used above
_setMedia : function(m){
    this._media = m;
},
```

(The reason I have an anonymous function there is I don't like assigning `var self = this` as inside the `require` blocks, `this` isn't the containing object.)

When I create the `new Player()` object in the init script, I can see that a new instance of either `Audio` or `Video` is being assigned correctly.  However, when I call the `p.setSource()` in the init script, I get an error that `_media` is null!

**Steps**

- Create Player

  - Parse configuration options (type, dimensions, etc). Internal `_media` object holds the instance of `Video` or `Audio`
- Allow setter method access outside the `Player` source **!! ERROR !!**

So my question, hopefully I gave enough context, but why the `_media` variable losing it's value?  Any methods inside the `Player` instance to be accessed from outside the Dijit's source shouldn't have any effect on the scope of internal variables, but that's what it seems is happening.  After the constructor returns, `_media` should be set! But using

```
setSource : function(s){
    console.log('Setting source: ', s, this._media)
    // outputs ("Setting source: path/to/video.webm', null)
},
```

...throws an error as the `_media` variable it's referencing inside `setSource` is supposedly null.

Hope that's clear :)

### Update

Wish I could give you guys both the checkmark!  Thank you for taking the time to help out.

@Frode: There definitely were some async issues that forced me to learn and try more with the structure, all of which failed, leading to this update.  I think at some points the files were cached, leading to inconsistent variable content.

@phusick: I hybridized your suggestion which is posted below.

I thought about redoing the structure of how the Player would be instantiated, the object arg and the like, but decided to do the following, in case anyone hits this issue...

I combined the `Audio` and `Video` classes into the `_Media` file, using this structure (code removed for brevity)

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare'], function(declare){
    var _base = declare("_Media", null, {        
        constructor : function(type){
            this._type = type;
        },
        // etc
    })
    return {
        Video : function(){
            return declare("Video", _base, {
                constructor : function(){
                    this.inherited(arguments, ['video'])
                }
                // etc
            })()
        },
        Audio : function(){
            return declare("Audio", _base, {
                constructor : function(){
                    this.inherited(arguments, ['audio'])
                }
                // etc
            })()
        },
    }
})
```

...that way there's only one file being loaded initially and it contains both subclasses.  Better than loading 2 separate files when one won't be used, IMO.

For the player type instance it then became:

```
this._media = opts.type && opts.type == 'video' ? new Media.Video() : new Media.Audio();
```

So far so good! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the constructor returns, _media should be set!

I think this is where you take a wrong step. Keep in mind that require is an asynchronous function!

However, I'm a little confused by this line in your constructor (specifically, the comment):

```
console.log(this._media) // also outputs the correct object, "a"
```

Are you 100% sure this outputs "a" and not a null? If you are, please ignore the rest of my answer, because then I've misunderstood something :)

Ok, if you're still reading, I'll try to explain asynchronous require. When you call:

```
require([".../Video",".../Audio"], function(Video, Audio) {
    // do something and set _media
});
```

you are basically saying: "Browser, you go fetch the Video and Audio modules for me in the background, while I continue with my next line of code. When you've fetched them, run that function I gave you which sets _media."

In other words, it may take a long time before require() finishes and `_media` is set, but your code continues right away. So when you call setSource, require() may not be done yet (in fact, it may not even have started downloading anything).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I seeee... thank you for the reminder of the asynchronous nature of `require`.  I looked more into the docs and learned a thing or two based on your answer.  I'll work on it some more later on and give an update.

Answer (score 1):

@Frode is right. Actually, even if the asynchronous operation would be fast enough it won't work, because JavaScript is single-threaded and asynchronous callbacks go into the Event Queue and are executed one after another via [Event Loop](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#asynchronous-events).

Please see also my answer to [Dojo 1.7 how to use dojo components outside of require()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631410/dojo-1-7-how-to-use-dojo-components-outside-of-require/10632689#10632689).

Is there any reason why your *player.js* does not look like this:

```
define([
    "sg/player/component/Video",
    "sg/player/component/Audio"
], function(
    Video,
    Audio
) {

    return declare([SomeSuperClass], {

        constructor: function(opts) {
            var media = opts.type && opts.type == "video" ? new Video() : new Audio();
            this._setMedia(media);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Its funny you mention that link as I saw it while researching away from the house not too long before you responded.  Reason I don't load the Video and Audio right away is they may not be needed.  I need like a synchronous conditional require block, I'll take a look at deferreds but I'll probably just combine Audio and Video into one Media class/file.  Thanks!